# How can I fetch queries after login?

Tags: reactjs, authentication, fetch, apollo

I'm working with React and Apollo.

I have a Login mutation to authenticate the user in the backend, this mutation returns a token that I save in a cookie, first question, Save a JWT token inside a cookie, is secure enough?
After the login, I want to fetch data with the queries inside refetchQueries, but the problem is that by the time Apollo refetch those queries the token it's not inside the header of the request so the backend doesn't let the query succeed. 
Where is the best place and time to fetch those queries after a successful login?

This is my code:

```
const [, setAuthToken, removeAuthToken] = useAuthToken();

    const [loginMutation, mutationResults] = useMutation(LOG_IN, {
        onCompleted: (data) => {
            setAuthToken(data.logIn.token);
        },
        refetchQueries: [
            { query: GET_ALL_GROUPS },
            { query: GET_ALL_CLASSES },
            { query: GET_ALL_ASSISTANTS },
        ],
        awaitRefetchQueries: true,
    });
```

```
export const useAuthToken = () => {
    const [cookies, setCookie, removeCookie] = useCookies([TOKEN_NAME]);

    const setAuthToken = (authToken) => setCookie(TOKEN_NAME, authToken);

    const removeAuthToken = () => removeCookie(TOKEN_NAME);

    return [cookies[TOKEN_NAME], setAuthToken, removeAuthToken];
};
```

```
new ApolloLink((operation, forward) => {
        if (authToken) {
            operation.setContext({
                headers: {
                    authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
                },
            });
        }
        return forward(operation);
    });
```

```
export const useApolloClient = () => {
    const [authToken] = useAuthToken();
    return new ApolloClient({
        link: authLink(authToken).concat(httpLink),
        cache,
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

About storing your JWT and best practices you can check [this post](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/#jwt_persist). you can get the value directly from the cookie instead of trying to get it from state if you need to change the header in the same render that mutation is completed. Another option would be to invalidate the cache of those queries after the state is set, you can [invalidate them manually](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-interaction/), pass a different cache instance to Apollo, or maybe have a different Apollo client for authenticated users.